# How do I increase the partition size of my ubuntu 18.04 via gparted

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

Here's the screenshot of my gparted window, I want to increase the size of my ubuntu partition (60.41 GB) using the unallocated size.

How do I achieve this? I have dual boot with Windows 10.

[image: ss of gparted]

If possible, it would be preferred if the solution does not involve using a live CD/Pen drive (kind of urgent and I don't have one)

Edit:
My resize option is showing disabled for `ext4` even though I have `unallocated` just above it. Should it be below it? If yes then how do I achieve that?

[image: ss of resize]

Thank you :)

Comment: You can't resize the partition/drive when you are using it. So, you need a Live CD or Pen drive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move it first, just grab the partition and drag it to the left, then resize it.

Comment: No way!! That will cause complete boot failure, if that partition contains /boot

Comment: And that's easy to repair with a live USB. And from the look of it none of the partitions on /dev/sdb seems to have a /boot partition.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.